# facebook javascript sdk - how to check if user likes page without fb.login pop up

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have a javascript function that uses fb.login to retrieve the users info and checks to see if the user likes my fb page. fb.login causes a pop up where the user must click a login button. If the user likes my page i need to first create a cookie then redirect them to the main app:

```
function checkUser() {
    var page_id = "my id goes here"; //
    FB.login(function (response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
            FB.api('/me', function (response) {
                var fql_query = "SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id = " + page_id + "and uid=" + response.id;
                var the_query = FB.Data.query(fql_query);
                the_query.wait(function (rows) {

                    if (rows.length == 1 && rows[0].uid == response.id) {
                        //$("#container_like").show();/
                        //set cookie
                        document.cookie = "fbId=" + response.id;


                        window.location = "/kisses.aspx";


                    } else {
                        $("#likepageholder").show();
                        //$("#container_notlike").show();
                        //window.location = "/kisses.aspx";
                        //and here you could get the content for a non liker in ajax...
                    }
                });

            });
        } else {
            console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
        }
    });
}
```

If there a way around using fb.login to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Unfortunately, you need the user to log in (and grant your app basic permissions [based on the appId you use in FB.init) in order to query the user's likes.

That being said, it looks like your code should work.